# Best way to reading large amounts of xml's

Tags: c#, xml

What is the best approach on reading large amounts of xml files (I need to read 8000 xml's) and do some computations on them, and have best speed on it? Is it ok using a xmlreader and returning the nodes i'm interested in in a list? Or is it faster when reading the node, also to do some computations on it? I tried the second approach(Returning the nodes in a list, as values, because I tried writing my application with as much modules as possible). I am using C#, but this is not relevant.

Thank you.

Comment: have you done time trials on your two options? It seems like you have already done the work...

Comment: Yes, the first one runs in 3 minutes, and the second in 13 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it ok using a xmlreader and returning the nodes i'm interested in in a list? Or is it faster when reading the node, also to do some computations on it?

I can't say whether returning a list is ok or not, because I don't know how large each file is, which would be more important in this regard than the number of XML documents.

However, it certainly *could* be very expensive, if an XML document, and hence the list produced, were very large.

Conversely, reading the node and calculating as you go will certainly be quicker to start producing results, and use less memory and hence faster in a degree ranging from negligible to so considerable as to have other approaches be infeasible, depending on just how large that source data is. It's the approach I take if I either have a strong concern with performance, or a good reason to suspect such a large dataset.

Somewhere between the two, is the approach of an `IEnumerable<T>` implementation that yields objects as it reads, along the lines of:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeObject> ExtractFromXml(XmlReader rdr)
{
  using(rdr)
    while(rdr.Read())
      if(rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && rdr.LocalName = "thatElementYouReallyCareAbout")
      {
         var current = /*Code to create a SomeObject from the XML goes here */
         yield return current;
      }
}
```

As with producing a list, this separates the code doing the calculation from that which parses the XML, but because you can start enumerating through it with a `foreach` before it has finished that parsing, the memory use can be less, as will the time to start the calculation. This makes little difference with small documents, but a lot if they are large.

Comment: This reduced time from almost 14 to 4 minutes, thanks! Another problem of mine, would be that my point of interest are two xml nodes, do I need to do this parsing for each of the nodes, or is theere a different approach that I can handle?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean there. The above checks on each node as it goes, through, but checking and ignoring is pretty fast. If you are at a point where you can know you won't care about anything else in a given XML document you can use `yield break` to stop processing at that point, and move straight on to the next file. Is that the sort of thing you are wondering about?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have personally come up with to deal with XML files is by taking advantage of the .Net's XmlSerializer class. You can define a model for your xml and create a List of that model where you keep your xml data then:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("OutPutPath")) { 

            new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Model>)).Serialize(sw, Models);
            sw.WriteLine();

}
```

you can read the file and deserilize the data and then assign them back to the model by calling the `Deserialize` method.

Comment: That won't do anything until it has deserialised the entire object, and would need to have that entire object in memory. It could also contain information from the XML that isn't relevant to the task, which is pointlessly wasting time and memory.

Comment: @JonHanna: you are right, the advantage of it is that, it allows for reading the xml data at once. After it has been loaded into memory then we can do whatever we wanna do on the data using Linq, very much like EF. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's a viable approach generally, but here the OP is specifically concerned about what they describe as a large amount of input data (though they could perhaps be misjudging that).

Comment: @JonHanna: I confused the 8000 XML file with 8000 XML Lines, you are so right Jon, this approach is not efficient in this scenario since it requires creating model for each xml file.

Comment: Funny, the one thing that has me thinking your approach *might* be okay, is I'm not sure they don't perhaps indeed mean 8000 files since (if those files are individually short) would be okay; calling your approach 8000 times on short files won't be much worse than doing so with the answer I'm working on. It really does depend on the size of the actual files.

Comment: files are between 2-10 kb each.

Comment: Is linq to xml a good approach? I only need to nodes from each xml's. Btw, if I would use linq to xml, when selecting all values of a node in a list, and imediatly afterwards selecting the values of a different node in another list, would the xml file be processed once or twice?

Comment: At that size, I would expect an approach like my to beat one like this on performance, but I wouldn't be 100% sure without testing. I'd be pretty sure mine wouldn't be slower, but it's worth noting that this answer could perhaps be more reusable in other uses of the same data, which would be a big reason to favour it.

Comment: @Jon Hanna, so what is our approach?

Comment: I saw it, thanks for the answer, I will try it out, and do some time measuring on it.

Comment: @patentul: I'd personally go for Jon's answer, his answer is more reasonable since you may not require all the nodes from the xml file.

Comment: Linq to XML is also a viable approach. In general, there are enough pros and cons to both my answer, this answer, Linq2XML, and also approaches using XmlDocument in different situations, that it's worth learning a bit about each of them. My approach, for example, would be absolutely terrible in cases where you might have to refer back in a document part-way through the process.